# Resources in net standard library project?

Tags: xamarin, .net-standard

I am intending on using a javascript sensor fusion library in a Xamarin app - and potentially also in watch projects. In my net standard library I have:

[image]

The Ahrs file contains:

```
public class Ahrs
{
    static ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine();
    static FileScriptSource fileScript = new FileScriptSource("./index.js"); // <-- invalid file path
    public static double Run()
    { // file notfound
        engine.Evaluate(fileScript);
        return engine.CallGlobalFunction<double>("update", 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

... where I attempt to call a method `update` inside my `js` file with [Jurassic](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic/wiki)

Is there some way I can add the `index.js` file to my net standard library and run it from the `Ahrs` file all inside net standard library?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me if I make the path `"index.js"` rather than `"./index.js"`

```cs
public class Ahrs
{
    static ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine();
    static FileScriptSource fileScript = new FileScriptSource("index.js"); // <-- valid file path
    public static double Run()
    { // file found
        engine.Evaluate(fileScript);
        return engine.CallGlobalFunction<double>("update", 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

I also made the javascript file's properties:

- Build Action : `Embedded resource`
- Copy to Output Directory : `Copy always`

[image]

Comment: It could be that it is working/should be working. I stopped getting file not found exception following your suggestion.
I do get into another error though which I raised an issue about: https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic/issues/169

Comment: On Android I get: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file "/index.js"'` - even though I used `new FileScriptSource("index.js")` :/

Comment: I’ll take a look today, I suspect this is due to it not being in the same assembly when you build but I’ll create a dummy project and test it out